# D3Js graph not working on Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I want to implement a graph using d3.js in my angular web application. Initially, I used the code from this [site](https://bl.ocks.org/cjrd/6863459). I copied all the copy between the script tag and paste into my controller file, the css code into my css file and the html from the site to my html file. If this is confusing, I will show an example below. Everything is working good when I m using the code from this site.
However, I tried to implement a different d3.js graph from this [site](http://jsfiddle.net/syedbilal/Lrywwb2L/) and followed the same method as I did before, this time, it is not working.

I tried to paste my code here, but it doesnt look tidy. So here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4z3ovkfq/)
`BuildVerticaLTree(treeData, "#tree");`

Moreover, the js code is working if implemented under a script tag in the html page. Example like below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        //build tree
        function BuildVerticaLTree(treeData, treeContainerDom) {
            var margin = { top: 40, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120 };
            var width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left;
            var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            var i = 0, duration = 750;
            var tree = d3.layout.tree()
                .size([height, width]);
            var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
                .projection(function (d) { return [d.x, d.y]; });
            var svg = d3.select(treeContainerDom).append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
              .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
            root = treeData;

            update(root);
            function update(source) {
                // Compute the new tree layout.
                var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
                    links = tree.links(nodes);
                // Normalize for fixed-depth.
                nodes.forEach(function (d) { d.y = d.depth * 100; });
                // Declare the nodes…
                var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
                    .data(nodes, function (d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });
                // Enter the nodes.
                var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .attr("transform", function (d) {
                        return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
                    }).on("click", nodeclick);
                nodeEnter.append("circle")
                 .attr("r", 10)
                    .attr("stroke", function (d) { return d.children || d._children ? "steelblue" : "#00c13f"; })
                    .style("fill", function (d) { return d.children || d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });
                //.attr("r", 10)
                //.style("fill", "#fff");
                nodeEnter.append("text")
                    .attr("y", function (d) {
                        return d.children || d._children ? -18 : 18;
                    })
                    .attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .text(function (d) { return d.name; })
                    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
                // Transition nodes to their new position.
                //horizontal tree
                var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
                nodeUpdate.select("circle")
                    .attr("r", 10)
                    .style("fill", function (d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });
                nodeUpdate.select("text")
                    .style("fill-opacity", 1);


                // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
                var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")"; })
                    .remove();
                nodeExit.select("circle")
                    .attr("r", 1e-6);
                nodeExit.select("text")
                    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
                // Update the links…
                // Declare the links…
                var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
                    .data(links, function (d) { return d.target.id; });
                // Enter the links.
                link.enter().insert("path", "g")
                    .attr("class", "link")

                    .attr("d", function (d) {
                        var o = { x: source.x0, y: source.y0 };
                        return diagonal({ source: o, target: o });
                    });
                // Transition links to their new position.
                link.transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                .attr("d", diagonal);


                // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
                link.exit().transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("d", function (d) {
                        var o = { x: source.x, y: source.y };
                        return diagonal({ source: o, target: o });
                    })
                    .remove();

                // Stash the old positions for transition.
                nodes.forEach(function (d) {
                    d.x0 = d.x;
                    d.y0 = d.y;
                });
            }

            // Toggle children on click.
            function nodeclick(d) {
                if (d.children) {
                    d._children = d.children;
                    d.children = null;
                } else {
                    d.children = d._children;
                    d._children = null;
                }
                update(d);
            }
        }

        var treeData =
    {
        "name": "BU Head",
        "children": [
          {
              "name": "Manager",
              "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Team Lead",
                     "children": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Team Lead",
                    "children": []
                }
              ]
          },
          {
              "name": "Manager",
              "children": []
          }
        ]
    };
        BuildVerticaLTree(treeData, "#tree");
    });
</script>
<div class="container">
    <div id = "tree"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: You had a lot of syntax errors in your fiddle, especially around how you declared your module and controller (you were passing the `TreeController` into itself, for one thing). I cleaned it up a bunch [in this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kf8EqMPSZwS22EJD8fnf?p=preview), so now something is at least rendering.

Comment: @BennettAdams Thank you for your reply. Actually this is a working code that is taken from the website directly did not make any changes.

Comment: The `BuildVerticaLTree` function might have been taken from a website, but `angular
    .module('treeProject')
    .controller('TreeController', ['backendService','$location','$log','$routeParams','$scope', TreeController]);` is not valid. The title of your post suggests that your d3 code is not working in angular, and I'm suggesting that's part of the problem.

Comment: @BennettAdams Yeah I just checked the code. And its rendering as you mentioned. I will continue to work from this new code. Thank you very much.